# boostrap datetimepicker showing begining date and time while tab out

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have two fields, one is textbox and another one is datefield.
If i tabbed out from textbox  to datefield, date picker is showing the begging of the date(december, 1899). But my requirement is to show the current date.

But it is working with static data using the parameter **data-date="21/04/2015"**. But not working with the dynamic data. i.e(data-date="dates" )

### controller

```
$scope.assignedDate = new Date();
$scope.dates = $filter('date')($scope.assignedDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

### view

```
<div class="input-group date form_date"  data-date="dates" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-ng-model="checkDate"  date-picker="{weekStart: 1,todayBtn: true, autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true, startView: 2, minView: 2}" date-picker>
  <input type="text" id="chqdt" name="chqdt" class="form-control input-appen inputDatepicker"  placeholder="Date" data-ng-model="checkDate" data-ng-disabled="optionalSearch == 'bankCode'" />
     <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar add-on"></span>
     </span>
</div>
```

### directive

```
app.directive('datePicker', function () {
      return {
            // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
            restrict: 'A',
            // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element).datetimepicker(scope.$eval(attrs.datePicker));
            }
        };
    });
```

### jQuery datetime plugin

*http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/*

[image]

Comment: Why do you have 2 `date-picker` directives attached to your div element?

Comment: that is for integrating jQuery plugin with angular